# GAN Generator accuracy reaches 100%

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to create modern art using GAN following the Medium blog. [Generating Modern Art using GAN](https://towardsdatascience.com/generating-modern-arts-using-generative-adversarial-network-gan-on-spell-39f67f83c7b4). The problem is that when I run the network, the Generator accuracy reaches 100% in the second iteration and stays there. What can I do to improve this?

```
def build_generator(noise_size, channels):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(4 * 4 * 256, activation='relu',       input_dim=noise_size))
    model.add(Reshape((4, 4, 256)))
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    for i in range(GENERATE_RES):
        model.add(UpSampling2D())
        model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, padding='same'))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.summary()
    model.add(Conv2D(channels, kernel_size=3, padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    inputs = Input(shape=(noise_size,))
    generated_image = model(inputs)
    
    return Model(inputs, generated_image)

def build_discriminator(image_shape):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, strides=2,
    input_shape=image_shape, padding='same'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=((0, 1), (0, 1))))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    input_image = Input(shape=image_shape)
    validity = model(input_image)
    return Model(input_image, validity)
```

This is the code for generator and discriminator

This is the combined model:

```
image_shape = (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_CHANNELS)

optimizer = Adam(lr=1.5e-4, beta_1=0.5)

discriminator = build_discriminator(image_shape)
discriminator.trainable = False

discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

generator = build_generator(NOISE_SIZE, IMAGE_CHANNELS)

random_input = Input(shape=(NOISE_SIZE,))

generated_image = generator(random_input)

validity = discriminator(generated_image)

combined = Model(random_input, validity)
combined.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

y_real = np.ones((BATCH_SIZE, 1))
y_fake = np.zeros((BATCH_SIZE, 1))

fixed_noise = np.random.normal(0,1, (PREVIEW_ROWS* PREVIEW_COLS, NOISE_SIZE))

cnt = 1

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    idx = np.random.randint(0, training_data.shape[0], BATCH_SIZE)
    x_real = training_data[idx]
    
    noise = np.random.normal(0,1, (BATCH_SIZE, NOISE_SIZE))
    x_fake = generator.predict(noise)
    
    discriminator_metric_real = discriminator.train_on_batch(x_real, y_real)
    
    discriminator_metric_generated = discriminator.train_on_batch(x_fake, y_fake)
    
    discriminator_metric = 0.5 * np.add(discriminator_metric_real, discriminator_metric_generated)
    
    generator_metric = combined.train_on_batch(noise, y_real)
    
    if(epoch % SAVE_FREQ == 0):
        save_images(cnt, fixed_noise)
        cnt += 1
        print(f"{epoch} epoch, Discriminator accuracy: {100*discriminator_metric[1]}, Generator accuracy: {100*generator_metric[1]}")
```

This is the problem:

```
0 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 37.5, Generator accuracy: 50.0
100 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 37.5, Generator accuracy: 62.5
200 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 62.5, Generator accuracy: 75.0
300 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 37.5, Generator accuracy: 50.0
400 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 56.25, Generator accuracy: 87.5
500 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 56.25, Generator accuracy: 87.5
600 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 25.0, Generator accuracy: 75.0
700 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 37.5, Generator accuracy: 100.0
800 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 18.75, Generator accuracy: 100.0
900 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 31.25, Generator accuracy: 87.5
1000 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 18.75, Generator accuracy: 100.0
1100 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 37.5, Generator accuracy: 100.0
1200 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 37.5, Generator accuracy: 87.5
1300 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 25.0, Generator accuracy: 100.0
1400 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 31.25, Generator accuracy: 100.0
1500 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 25.0, Generator accuracy: 100.0
1600 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 37.5, Generator accuracy: 100.0
1700 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 37.5, Generator accuracy: 100.0
1800 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 37.5, Generator accuracy: 100.0
1900 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 6.25, Generator accuracy: 100.0
2000 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 25.0, Generator accuracy: 100.0
2100 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 25.0, Generator accuracy: 87.5
2200 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 43.75, Generator accuracy: 100.0
2300 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 18.75, Generator accuracy: 100.0
2400 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 18.75, Generator accuracy: 100.0
2500 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 18.75, Generator accuracy: 100.0
2600 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 25.0, Generator accuracy: 100.0
2700 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 25.0, Generator accuracy: 100.0
2800 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 18.75, Generator accuracy: 100.0
2900 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 25.0, Generator accuracy: 100.0
3000 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 18.75, Generator accuracy: 100.0
3100 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 31.25, Generator accuracy: 100.0
3200 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 37.5, Generator accuracy: 100.0
3300 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 25.0, Generator accuracy: 100.0
3400 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 37.5, Generator accuracy: 100.0
3500 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 37.5, Generator accuracy: 100.0
3600 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 37.5, Generator accuracy: 100.0
3700 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 25.0, Generator accuracy: 100.0
3800 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 18.75, Generator accuracy: 100.0
3900 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 31.25, Generator accuracy: 100.0
4000 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 12.5, Generator accuracy: 100.0
4100 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 50.0, Generator accuracy: 100.0
4200 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 31.25, Generator accuracy: 100.0
4300 epoch, Discriminator accuracy: 25.0, Generator accuracy: 100.0
```

Comment: What makes you think its a problem, and why do you even have accuracy in the generator?

Comment: I don't know much about GANs and I read that the generator is supposed to learn over a number of iterations. Also, the generator accuracy is actually the entire model's accuracy so I'm confused. In addition, the model is still producing noise as it's output and after the 700th epoch, it more or less creates the same images :(

Comment: Accuracy is not a metric to see if your GAN is learning, specially since GANs do not do classification, which is the only setting where accuracy is a a valid metric.

Comment: Then how do I improve the model? It seems as if its stopped learning :(